# Width of dl element

Tags: html, css, phpbb

I am modifying for my purpose the phpbb poll display. This is my current html code when result display is on:

```
<div class="content">
        <h2>Question</h2>
        <p class="author">bla bla <strong>אחת</strong></p>
            <dl class="">
                <dt><label for="vote_1">option1</label></dt>
                <dd style="width: auto;"><input type="radio" name="vote_id[]" id="vote_1" value="1" /></dd><dd class="resultbar"><div class="pollbar" style="width:77%">10</div></dd>
                <dd>77%</dd>
            </dl>

            <dl class="">
                <dt><label for="vote_2">Option 2</label></dt>
                <dd style="width: auto;"><input type="radio" name="vote_id[]" id="vote_2" value="2" /></dd><dd class="resultbar"><div class="pollbar" style="width:23%">3</div></dd>
                <dd>23%</dd>
            </dl>

            <dl class="">
                <dt><label for="vote_3">Option 3</label></dt>
                <dd style="width: auto;"><input type="radio" name="vote_id[]" id="vote_3" value="3" /></dd><dd class="resultbar"><div class="pollbar" style="width:0%">0</div></dd>
                <dd>No votes</dd>
            </dl>

            <dl>
                <dt>&nbsp;</dt>
                <dd class="resultbar">Total : 13</dd>
            </dl>

            <dl style="border-top: none;">
                <dt>&nbsp;</dt>
                <dd class="resultbar"><input type="submit" name="update" value="submit" class="button1" /></dd>
            </dl>


    </div>

    <span class="corners-bottom"><span></span></span></div>
    <input type="hidden" name="creation_time" value="1326810654" />
```

The problem is this: in phpbb, the  elements have the same width as the "content" div, and so they are displayed line-by-line. However, in my code the  elements have width 0 (what is the exact meaning of width 0? On-screen they have width larger than 0) and all the -s are displayed in the same line.

I looked around the css files, but as far as I can see there is no difference. What is the relevant property here? Setting 's "width" style option in the css file to 100% and "inherit" has no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks like a strange presentation of tabular data (something that should be presented using `<table>` elements), and probably the intent is to use CSS for the purpose but somehow the relevant CSS code has gone missing.

Without CSS, each `dt` and `dd` element is rendered each on a line of its own, because this is the default rendering in HTML.

The percentage widths are presumably meant to act as graphic representation of percentages, so that e.g. 73% corresponds to a 73% wide block. This cannot be seen, however, without some CSS that makes the blocks visible with e.g. border or background color. The idea fails e.g. for 0%, for obvious reasons.

Without more context, including CSS being applied, it’s difficult to say much more.

Comment: You are correct. The problem was caused by "display:inline" in the CSS.